# In Titanium, what's the difference between the pause event and registerBackgroundService in ios?

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

In a nutshell, what's the point of having Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService when you can do a similar thing with attaching a function to the "pause" event? Are there any differences between the two approaches in Titanium?
e.g.
version 1:
app.js:

```
service = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({
    url:"bg.js"
});
```

bg.js:

```
var sec = 0;
setInterval(function(){console.log('counting' + sec); sec = sec + 1}, 1000);
```

Version 2:
app.js

```
Titanium.App.addEventListener('pause', function(){
    var sec = 0;
    setInterval(function(){console.log('counting' + sec); sec = sec + 1}, 1000);
});
```

Version 1 & Version 2 do the exact same thing (when the app is put in the background).

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 and Version 2 are not doing the same thing. [Background service](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService) is a service that runs when the application is placed in the background and it will stop automatically when the application returns from background. And it can invoke [Titanium.App.iOS.LocalNotification](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.LocalNotification).

[pause](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-pause) is an event which is fired when the application transitions from active to inactive state on a multitasked system. This event fires when the user leaves the application or for certain types of temporary interruptions such as a notification or incoming phone call.

From Documentation,

> Note that calls to functions that modify the UI during this event may
> be partially executed, up to the UI call before the suspension. See
> paused event. If this happens, the remainder of the code will be
> executed after the application is resumed, but before the resume event
> is triggered.

Both are different and doing different jobs

Comment: I know that their description is different but in reality the same thing happens when/if you use the two versions of the code that I provided.

IF you attach the function (the counter) to "pause" event and just suspend the app (either by pressing the home button or ...), the function that is attached to pause will fire.

In fact, I tested the above code and they provide the exact same result. They both count to 173 and get shutdown by the OS after 173 seconds.